# In Jinja Template, some lines of code are in {} and some are in {% %}. What's the difference?

Tags: django, jinja2

I am learning Django and I am unable to get why some code is merely in { } brackets and while other is {% %}. What'the difference?

Example is given below:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
     <li> <a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a> </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{%...%}` block executes a statement, while the `{{...}}` block evaluates an expression and outputs the returning value of the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentatition, it is pretty clear and full with various sample code.
[Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#synopsis)